# Load javascript file dynamically by appending script tag to body

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load library script files dynamically, iff they are not loaded by any other page. Here, `container` is just a div element.

```
if($ === undefined ){
   $(".container").append('<script src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script>')
   $(".container").append('<script src="../static/js/dt_jq_ui.js"></script>');
   $(".container").append('<script src="../static/js/report_app.js"></script>')
}
```

But it fails and the firefox console error is,
[image]

Error text is,

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
$(".container").append('<script src="../static/js/jquery.js">
```

Why is the html string with `script` tag marked as invalid?

Comment: Please include the error as text. That image is impossible to read.

Comment: So... you're loading jQuery with jQuery when jQuery isn't present?

Comment: added the error text

Comment: brilliant Oka.... i was dumb... the curse of copy n paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it event enter the `if block`?

Answer is `no` because `$` is treated like a `variable`

1.Variables that are actually 'not defined', i.e. they don't exists as a given name isn't bound in the current lexical environment. Accessing such a variable will throw an error, but using typeof won't and will return 'undefined'. In contrast, accessing non-existing properties will not throw an error and return undefined instead (and you may use the in operator or the hasOwnProperty() method to check if properties actually do exist).

2.Existing variables which have not been assigned a value (which is common because of var hoisting) or which have been explicitly set to undefined. Accessing such a variable will return undefined, typeof will return 'undefined'.

3.Existing variables which have been explicitly set to null. Accessing such a variable will return null, typeof will return 'object'. Note that this is misleading: null is not an object, but a primitive value of type Null (which has the consequence that you can't return null from constructor functions - you have to throw an error instead to denote failure).

Answer (score 2):

Use this way to include scripts:

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
     newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newscript.async = true;
     newscript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
.append('\<script src="../static/js/jquery.js"\>\<\/script\>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "../static/js/jquery.js";
$(".container").append(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

well, If $ is undefined,
this will generate an error:

```
$(".container")
```

becase $ is not a function, its undefined!